# How to wait until all loaders disappears using Selenium WebDriver through Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, loader, webdriverwait

I am using selenium web driver and I need to wait until all loaders disappear. I have 12 widgets on dashboard page and I need to wait until all widgets are loaded. Loader shows on each widget. I have used both following ways but nothing works and no errors, it just passes on to next statement.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60)
.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loader')]")));
```

```
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.loader")));
```

[image: This is the loader HTML, when it shows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are having total 12 widgets on dashboard page and you need to wait until all widgets are loaded you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the [`invisibilityOfAllElements()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfAllElements-java.util.List-) and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.loader"))));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='loader']"))));
  ```

Comment: invisibilityOfAllElements() is working perfectly for me with cssSelector. Thanks a million :-)