# Element is not clickable at point because another element obscures it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am using Selenium webdriver and i got the following exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <div id="nav-icon3"> is not clickable at point (21,37) because another element <div class="loader-section section-left"> obscures it
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Session ID: 868f9daa-dd6c-4b53-846d-7323e7b0408e
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

My code is given below.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("nav-icon3"));
      JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
      executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
    driver.findElement(By.id("nav-icon3")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='slide-out']/li/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='slide-out']/li/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li/a")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("newTravelerLink")).click();
```

Comment: Put explicit wait instead of implicit wait and check for element to be clickable condition. if still it does not work check manually if `<div class="loader-section section-left">` element is overlapping `<div id="nav-icon3">` on UI.

Comment: share the html code of the element where this exception generated.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem while doing an adFly bot.

Using waits or similar methods is **often useless**, don't rely on using elementobeclickable() too.

The only way to get around it is to get all the element at that position and remove all of those from the page except the one you're interested in.

Step 1:

Get the X and Y Points of EVERY div, iframe, span in the page.
Try out these three WebElements first (using getX() and getY() methods of Point
(https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.openqa.selenium.Point&method=getX) through a cycle.

put them all in an ArrayList called let's say, overlappingElements,

then remove from the ArrayList the obscuredElement.

Step 2:

Remove every WebElement that overlap over your WebElement in another cycle.

```
JavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavaScriptExecutor) driver;

for(int i = 0; i < overlappingElements.size(); i++) {

jsExecutor.executeScript(
    "arguments[0].parentNode.removeChild(arguments[0])", overlappingElements.get(i));

}
```

Step 3: Just click() on obscuredElement.

Answer (score 0):

If you code a method to wait you can use that wait method in your project

```
private static WebElement waitForElement(By locator, int timeout)
{
    WebElement element=new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    return element;
}
```

The above code is wait method

If you want to use this method

---

`waitForElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"),50);`
This for example ,you can use your web element here

Comment: Justin Lambert                                                                                                              Thank you so much for the response.When i put the code it says "Syntax error,Insert "Enumbody" to complete the block.                                                                          private static WebElement (driver.findElement(By.id("nav-icon3"),50)); { WebElement element=new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(driver.findElement(By.id("nav-icon3")))); return element; }

Comment: URL and your coding

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <div id="nav-icon3"> is not clickable at point (21,37) because another element <div class="loader-section section-left"> obscures it
```

...implies that the element `<div id="nav-icon3">` can't be clicked as the element `<div class="loader-section section-left">` obsecures it.

---

### Solution

To `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#nav-icon3"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-icon3']"))).click();
  ```

Incase the `click()` still fails you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) either for [**`invisibilityOf()`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.loader-section.section-left"))));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#nav-icon3"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='loader-section section-left']"))));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-icon3']"))).click();
  ```

Or for [**`invisibilityOfElementLocated()`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.loader-section.section-left")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#nav-icon3"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='loader-section section-left']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-icon3']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to wait until all loaders disappears using Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59574982/how-to-wait-until-all-loaders-disappears-using-selenium-webdriver-through-java/59575770#59575770)